# Turtle is drawing a line where I don't want it to

Tags: python, python-turtle, pong

I'm new ish to python and the turtle module and trying to make a pong game for a class assignment but i keep getting a line being drawn across the screen when my paddles appear. I've tried using tracer but it seems to have no effect.

sorry if my code is a bit messy and the solution is easy its just had me stumped.

```py
#import turtle for the background of the game (where the game is going to be played on)

import turtle

#creating the main screen/background
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title("JMR_Hercules_Pong")
turtle.bgcolor("black")
screen.setup(width = 800, height = 600)
screen.tracer(0)

#Requires two paddles one on the left one on the right

#left paddle
left_pad = turtle.Turtle() ##This creates a shape/device over the turtle background
left_pad.speed(0)

left_pad.shape("square")
left_pad.color("green")
left_pad.shapesize(stretch_wid=5,stretch_len=0.5)
left_pad.setx(-350)
turtle.pensize(2)
turtle.penup()

#right paddle
right_pad = turtle.Turtle()
right_pad.speed(0)
right_pad.shape("square")
right_pad.color("green")
right_pad.shapesize(5,0.5)
right_pad.setx(350)#sets the x coordinate so that you paddle goes to that x coord, goto wasn't working 
right_pad.sety(0)
turtle.pensize(2)
turtle.penup()
screen.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there might be two issues here. When you create your new Turtle objects for drawing the left paddle and right paddle, they are created by default at the center of the screen. First, you will need to call the .penup() method before moving the Turtle object using .setx(). This will stop that line appearing from the center to the edges of the screen. The other thing to note is that you need to use the actual Turtle object for the paddles when calling .penup() and .pensize() (currently, you are just referencing the turtle module itself).

So I'd recommend switching the following:

```py
left_pad = turtle.Turtle() ##This creates a shape/device over the turtle background
left_pad.speed(0)

left_pad.shape("square")
left_pad.color("green")
left_pad.shapesize(stretch_wid=5,stretch_len=0.5)
left_pad.setx(-350)
turtle.pensize(2)
turtle.penup()
```

to

```py
left_pad = turtle.Turtle() ##This creates a shape/device over the turtle background
left_pad.speed(0)

left_pad.shape("square")
left_pad.color("green")
left_pad.shapesize(stretch_wid=5,stretch_len=0.5)
left_pad.penup()
left_pad.setx(-350)
left_pad.pensize(2)
```

Then you would ideally want to do the same thing for the right paddle.

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on the issue " i keep getting a line being drawn across the screen when my paddles appear"
Lift the pen before positioning the paddles.

```
# import turtle for the background of the game (where the game is going to be played on)

import turtle

# creating the main screen/background
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title("JMR_Hercules_Pong")
turtle.bgcolor("black")
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
screen.tracer(0)

# Requires two paddles one on the left one on the right

# left paddle
left_pad = turtle.Turtle()  ##This creates a shape/device over the turtle background
left_pad.penup() # Lift the pen before moving the pad
left_pad.speed(0)
left_pad.shape("square")
left_pad.color("green")
left_pad.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=0.5)
left_pad.setx(-350)
turtle.pensize(2)
# left_pad.penup()

# right paddle
right_pad = turtle.Turtle()
right_pad.penup() # Lift the pen before moving the pad
right_pad.speed(0)
right_pad.shape("square")
right_pad.color("green")
right_pad.shapesize(5, 0.5)
right_pad.setx(
    350)  # sets the x coordinate so that you paddle goes to that x coord, goto wasn't working
right_pad.sety(0)
turtle.pensize(2)
# right_pad.penup()
screen.update()
```